# Need help with solving three simultaneous equations with three unknowns, and aren't linear.

Tags: linear-algebra

The question :

"Find the real number values that satisfy the following three equations simultaneously."

$xyz^3 = 24$

$xy^3z = 54$

$x^3yz = 6$

I'm struggling to solve this as they are not linear. So I believe I need to use the substitution method to solve them ?

I just need some hints to get started, as want to try and do it on my own for the most part.

Comment: This looks much harder than it actually is... Try to do algebraic manipulations by using multiplication/division of equations by each other and exponentiation.
For example, dividing equation 1 by equation 2 gives you already an equation independent of $x$...
(In fact, the equation is linear if considered in a strange space. But maybe that is something to find out on your own ;)

Comment: Take the logarithm on both sides of the 3 equations, your system becomes linear... (under the assumption that your unknowns are positive, which is true).

Answer (score 2):

Multiply all three equations together to get $(xyz)^5=7776=6^5$, whence $xyz=6$. This gives $x^2=1,y^2=9,z^2=4$.

One set of solutions is $(x,y,z)=(1,3,2)$. We cannot negate one or three of these numbers since that changes the sign of *all* the LHSs, but we can negate two numbers. Hence all real solutions are given by $(x,y,z)=(\pm1,\pm3,\pm2)$ with zero or two minus signs.

Comment: Genius indeed! Very elegant solution.